# Circular header dependency in ECS

Tags: c++, header, circular-dependency

I'm trying to implement an ECS pattern for a videogame in C++.

The three element of the pattern are mainly represented by a Manager (`EntityManager`, `ComponentManager`, `System Manager`) which are defined and implemented a three differents .h files (because of using of template).

I've also created a `Coordinator` class in another .h file which has a references to instance of all three manager classes, so I had to include the header file of the managers in the file.

The `System Manager` (well, actually the concrete Systems I had to implement) must have a reference to the `Coordinator` class to get the component from other entities. Therefore also the .h file for a generic system needs to include the .h of the `Coordinator` class, thus producing a circular header dependency.

I couldn't solve it with a simple forward declaration since I need to actually call methods of the `Coordinator` class (which is a Singleton at the moment).

The error Visual Studio 2019 gives me is

> "LNK2005 Error, ..., "already defined in ...)

Is there a way to solve it while keeping the described structure?
Thanks in advance!

**Coordinator.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "EntityManager.hpp"
#include "ComponentManager.hpp"
#include "SystemManager.hpp"
```

**SystemManager.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "System.hpp"
```

**System.hpp**
`#pragma once`

**PhysicsSystem.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "../Core/System.hpp"

class PhysicsSystem : public System
{
public:
    void Update(float dt);
};
```

**PhysicsSystem.cpp**

```
#include "PhysicsSystem.hpp"
#include "../Core/Coordinator.hpp"

void PhysicsSystem::Update(float dt)
{
    Coordinator* coordinator = Coordinator::GetInstance();
};
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Going to need some more detail here and a way to reproduce this issue if possible. Also, can you provide the full LNK2005 Error?